# If I leave my webcam (bultin Macbook) always on, may I reduce its life?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, webcam

If I leave my MacBook iSight camera always on, does its life get shortened?

Comment: Just curious - why would you keep it on all the time?

Comment: The reason is quite silly actually, but fun. I have a Thunderbolt display in front of me and a macbook on my left. My colleagues are using a table in front of me and I can´t see them. So I turn on both cameras and they can see me and I can see them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked with hardware for too many years.  My guess is that your camera life will not be significantly affected.  The camera is small with no moving parts, and fairly mature technology.

If you are leaving the computer unattended, and it is facing towards the sun (maybe sunrise or sunset?) you might want to take steps to make sure direct sunlight will not reach it.

Comment: So it appears I CAN leave it on the whole day, yes? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  But keep an eye on it, especially on software updates. Apple often optimise products (e.g. personal computers) for their purpose (e.g. personal computing) without regard to what users want them to do (e.g. being a webcam).